# Flutter PieChart Labels --how to make it works

Tags: flutter, charts

Im trying to make my PieChart Labels visible, but after set arcRenderDecorators it comes to

1. RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject#1bf0d NEEDS-PAINT
   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
   Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'
2. RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#5ff88 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
   Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'
3. RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#4a473 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
   Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'
4. RenderBox was not laid out: ChartContainerRenderObject#1bf0d
   'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
   Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'
   issues.

What kind of Widget I must to use to do it works. Please help.

````
 final List<DeveloperSeries> data = [

   DeveloperSeries(
     year: "2017",
     developers: 40000,
     barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue),
   ),
   DeveloperSeries(
     year: "2019",
     developers: 40000,
     barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue),
   ),
   DeveloperSeries(
     year: "2020",
     developers: 35000,
     barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue),
   ),
   DeveloperSeries(
     year: "2021",
     developers: 45000,
     barColor: charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue),
   ),
 ];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Center(
       child: DeveloperChart(
         data: data,
       )
     ),
   );
 }
}
class DeveloperChart extends StatelessWidget {
 final List<DeveloperSeries> data;

 DeveloperChart({required this.data});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   List<charts.Series<DeveloperSeries, String>> series = [
     charts.Series(
       id: "developers",
       data: data,
       domainFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.year,
       measureFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.developers,
       colorFn: (DeveloperSeries series, _) => series.barColor,
       labelAccessorFn: (DeveloperSeries row, _) => row.year,
     )
   ];

   return Container(
       height: 500,
       width: 500,
       child: Card(
         child: Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
           child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Text(
                   "Yearly Growth in the Flutter Community",
                   style: Theme
                       .of(context)
                       .textTheme
                       .bodyText2,
                 ),
                 Expanded(
                     child: charts.PieChart(series, animate: true,
                         defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
                             arcRendererDecorators: [
                               charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
                                   labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition
                                       .outside)
                             ])
                     )
                 )
               ]
           ),
         ),
       )
   );
 }
}```
````

Answer (score 3):

Same issue, I solved it by replacing:

```
charts.PieChart(
```

With:

```
charts.PieChart<String>(
```

Comment: Just to explain we use `String` as type param as series of type `charts.Series<DeveloperSeries, String>`